# Google Sheets. What's the formula for counting but checks conditions first?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I don't know if my question is correct but basically, I have a Google Form that accepts two inputs from these questions:

1. Text - Name
2. Integer - How many newspapers did you sell today?

With this, I have linked a Google Sheet for this Form, and every input of the employees, adds another entry to the sheet. The employees answers the form **every day**.

```
Form Responses 1
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+
| Timestamp |     Name     | How many newspapers did you sell today? |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+
|  June 11  | Kristine     | 12                                      |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+
|  June 11  | Jeffrey      | 11                                      |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+
|  June 12  | Kristine     | 5                                       |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+
|  June 12  | Jeffrey      | 9                                       |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

In the same Sheet, I made another sheet called "Tracker" that tracks the number of newspapers sold for each individual (Just think Jeffrey and Kristine are the only ones who are selling the newspapers).

```
Tracker
+--------------+-----------------+
|     Name     | Newspaper Count |
+--------------+-----------------+
| Kristine     | 17              |
+--------------+-----------------+
| Jeffrey      | 20              |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

What should be the formula for the newspaper count? I've tried brute-forcing it by using this formula for each individual (this example is for Kristine):

```
IF('Form Responses 1'!B2 = "Kristine", 'Form Responses 1'!C2, 0) + 
IF('Form Responses 1'!B3 = "Kristine", 'Form Responses 1'!C3, 0) + 
IF('Form Responses 1'!B4 = "Kristine", 'Form Responses 1'!C4, 0) +
IF('Form Responses 1'!B5 = "Kristine", 'Form Responses 1'!C5, 0) ...
```

But when another entry is added, somehow the formula also changes. The cells move like this:

```
IF('Form Responses 1'!B2 = "Kristine", 'Form Responses 1'!C2, 0) + 
IF('Form Responses 1'!B3 = "Kristine", 'Form Responses 1'!C3, 0) + 

IF('Form Responses 1'!B6 = "Kristine", 'Form Responses 1'!C6, 0) +
IF('Form Responses 1'!B7 = "Kristine", 'Form Responses 1'!C7, 0) ...
```

So what should be the proper formula to solve this problem?

Comment: The solution is using pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I used this:

```
QUERY('Form Responses 1'!B2:C,"SELECT SUM(C) WHERE B = 'Kristine'")
QUERY('Form Responses 1'!B2:C,"SELECT SUM(C) WHERE B = 'Jeffrey'")
```

Comment: let us know if you are interested in single-cell formula